# Ant design and ajax pagination with SWR

Tags: next.js, antd, swr

I have working on a project where the data comes paginated from the backend. I am using SWR for fetching the data. I went over the ant design's ajax example under table components (https://ant.design/components/table#components-table-demo-ajax). Everything work fine except that the tables don't render the pagers, they are stuck on page 1. The image below shows how it looks:
[image]

When I log the pagination props on the browser, this is what I get:
[image]

```
//state hook for setting parameters
 const [tableParams, setTableParams] = useState({
        pagination: {
            current: 1,
            pageSize: 50,
        },
    });

...

//when the data fetching with useSWR is successfull I set the table parameters like so:
 setTableParams({
     ...tableParams,
     pagination: {
         ...tableParams.pagination,
         total: businesses.count,
     },
 });
```

I am using nextjs-v13.4.10, swr-v2.2.0 and antd-v5.7.0